# Issue installing PyPar on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, installation, python

I am attempting to install pypar the parallel computing python toolbox on Ubuntu ver 14.04.1 LTS (code name trusty). Essentially I'm having installation errors and was wondering if  anybody knows what to do.

I have:

- downloaded pypar from http://code.google.com/p/pypar/ and unpacked it
- installed numpy using pip and openmpi
- used the command `python setup.py install` and got an error telling me to use the command `python compile_pypar_locally.py` which I did
- This seemed to work for the installation but now when I import I get the following error:

  ```
  import pypar
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "pypar.py", line 863, in <module>
      CDLL('libmpi.so', RTLD_GLOBAL)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
      self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
  OSError: libmpi.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
  ```

Would anybody know how to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What package did you install for openmpi? From the `README` file you should have installed `openmpi-bin` and `libopenmpi-dev`, have you got the second one?

Comment: Also, have you read section `COMPILE PYPAR LOCALLY` of this `README` file? They do mention the use of `compile_pypar_locally.py`, and explain that a path to the dir containing `mpiext.so` should be added to the PATH variable (try something like `PATH=$PATH:<dir_where_miext.so_is_located>`). Maybe the fact you had to compile locally could be related to a lack of root privilege?